# Web request error/Web Exception

Tags: c#, webclient, system.net.webexception

I am trying to get pdf file data using webclient but it is throwing an exception of
 **"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."**

Here are error details:

System.Net.WebException was caught

Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
  Source=System

StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)

Error Status: System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError

Here is the **code snippet** am using to download data:

```
try{
    WebClient cl = new WebClient();
    byte[] data = cl.DownloadData(URL);
}
catch(exception ex){

}
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

You should supply credentials. Similar to the following

```
try
{
     WebClient cl = new WebClient();
     cl.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
      byte[] data = cl.DownloadData(URL);
}
catch (exception ex)
{
}
```